# error while adding restsharp refernce

Tags: restsharp

I have a problem adding the reference of REstsharp.dll. It says:

> "Reference cannot be added to d:\Vinay sree\RestSharp-101.2\RestSharp.dll because it was not built using the Windows Phone runtime. Windows Phone Projects will work only with Windows Phone assemblies."

error while adding the reference for restsharp.dll. With that the sample given in the blogs doesnot work as it gives error Execute method cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Add a reference to RestSharp.WindowsPhone.dll and Newtonsoft.Json.WindowsPhone.dll as those are the version specific to the phone.